# Installing opencv in docker container

Tags: opencv, docker

I'm trying to install opencv for [this](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) project. In the original dockerfile, they didn't give instructions for installing opencv. The dockerfile portion is follows:

```
FROM python:3.4-slim

#RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    gfortran \
    git \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libav-tools  \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libjasper-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libopencv-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libtiff-dev \
    libvtk6-dev \
    pkg-config \
    python-dev \
    python-numpy \
    python-opencv \
    python-pycurl \
    qt5-default \
    unzip \
    webp \
    wget \
    zlib1g-dev 
    #&& apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN mkdir -p ~/opencv cd ~/opencv && \
    wget https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.2.0.zip && \
    unzip 3.2.0.zip && \
    rm 3.2.0.zip && \
    cd opencv-3.2.0 && \
    mkdir build && \ 
    cd build && \
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .. && \
    make -j4 && \
    make install && \ 
    ldconfig

RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cv2.cpython-34m.so /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cv2.so
    
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    gfortran \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    graphicsmagick \
    libgraphicsmagick1-dev \
    libatlas-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libboost-all-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    pkg-config \
    python3-dev \
    python3-numpy \
    software-properties-common \
    zip \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

    

    
RUN cd ~ && \
    mkdir -p dlib && \
    git clone -b 'v19.4' --single-branch https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git dlib/ && \
    cd  dlib/ && \
    python3 setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS
```

But when I'm doing `import cv2`, it's giving me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

When I'm doing `find / -name "cv.py"`, I'm getting

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv.py

And for this `find / -name "cv2.so"`, the result is

> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cv2.so
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so
>
> /opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/cv2.so

I don't know where I'm making the mistake. Can someone please guide me?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just `RUN pip install python-opencv`? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python

Comment: @Robert: No..it's not working that way. Using that command I can install opencv and import cv2. But when I'm trying to read a video file, it's not reading. That means opencv didnt install properly.